# How to track input parameter and result using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

Suppose i have following code :

```
    url_list = [

    "https://via.placeholder.com/480",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/490",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/500",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/510",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/520",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/530",
]


def download_file(url):
    html = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    return html.status_code

result = {} 
processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for url in url_list:
        processes.append(executor.submit(download_file, url))

for task in as_completed(processes):
    result.update({url: task.result()})
```

i would like to store in result mapping of url : result, something like

```
https://via.placeholder.com/480 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/490 : 200
```

But in result, i have following

```
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
https://via.placeholder.com/530 : 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are going against the same website, it definitely pays to use a `requests.Session` instance for retrieval. Second, you can store your `Future` instances returned by `submit` in a dictionary as the key and the URL used as the input parameter as the value. I have taken the liberty of renaming some variables so that they more closely correspond to what they are holding:

```python
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import requests

url_list = [

    "https://via.placeholder.com/480",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/490",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/500",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/510",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/520",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/530",
]

def download_file(session, url):
    html = session.get(url, stream=True)
    return html.status_code

result = {}
with requests.Session() as session:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(download_file, session, url): url for url in url_list}
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            # recover original URL:
            url = futures[future]
            result[url] = future.result()
print(result)
```